# Kusto query to cluster rows in a table and link clusters with original rows

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a simple question, but have not been able to find a solution yet.
I am using Azure data explorer, and I am in need of a kusto query that group similar rows together, and output clusters along with the original rows. Currently, the clustering functions that I have used including `autocluster` and `basket` only provide with row count related to the cluster as below.

For example, what I am after is finding the original 200 rows in segment 0, 91 rows in segment 1 and 2, rather than count in each segment.

[image]

I would massively appreciate it if someone can help me out to cluster rows in a table and link clusters with the original rows.

Cheers!

Comment: You said you need to groupy, can you please provide on which column you need to group and also provide the expected output and input

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Not really, I do not need to groupby columns. For example, how can find the 200 items in segment 0, 91 items in segment 1 and 2 above? Linking them them is the issue, not grouping.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. IFew years ago we considered implementing it but this cross join with the original table is very expensive and can explode in case you have many segments to join with the original big table. If you run the query by using  SDK from some client you can loop over the segments and fetch the record sets of each segment one by one.
Regardless, have a look at [log_reduce_full_fl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/functions-library/log-reduce-full-fl?tabs=query-defined&pivots=azuredataexplorer) and the other log_reduce functions, they are useful to cluster variable text logs in a single column.

Comment: Actually, looping over each segment is good enough for this case. However, I cannot find a key or column to link segments back to original rows. Am I missing out something there?